# How to add custom metadata to WordPress media with the REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am using wooThumbs plugin for wooCommerce which records a video link against images in the media library and this link is editable in the web page however there is no reference to it when calling

```
GET https://<site>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/281668
```

Although I can update the caption, alt text etc, I have tried every combination of updating it with variations of the following but the response (although no error) does not include the value.

```
POST https://<site>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/281668

{
    "_iconic_woothumbs_media": "test url"
}
```

Comment: Is the meta `_iconic_woothumbs_media` exist for any of the existing media on your site?